# Keep getting Reference Error: Document Is Not Defined when linking an external Javascript file to an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was following an online tutorial, but I got stuck when trying to link a Javascript file to an HTML file and running the Javascript file.

HTML File

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS For Beginners</title>
    <style>
        body{
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        ul{
            list-style: none;
        }

        ul li{
            padding: 5px;
            background: white;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        header{
            background: white;
            padding: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>JS For Beginners</h1>
    </header>

    <section class = "container">
        <form id="my-form">
            <h1>Add User</h1>
            <div class="msg"></div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email">
            </div>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <ul id="users"></ul>

    </section>

    <script src="manip.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript File

```
const a = document.getElementById("my-form");
const b = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Yet, I keep getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Todd Stowers\Documents\Javascript Tutorial\manip.js:2:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Even though I clearly sourced it in the HTML file. I am confused and at a lost of what to do

Comment: are you running the JavaScript in node?

Comment: It should work if you are running correctly via some server - https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-feather-1qkwl . Check for the console messages.

Comment: @ Tibebes.M - I am running it through the Visual Studio code runner extension

Comment: what if you just open the html file in the browser?

Comment: But how do I run the javascript then? Sorry if this sounds dumb I just started this and have been running all my JS files through the VS code runner